# In Typescript, is there a difference between types `object` and `Record<any, any>`?

Tags: typescript

Both types `object` and `Record<any, any>` appear to me to include the same set of valid objects, which is anything for which `typeof x === "object`. Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think Javascript objects can have keys that are complex types. Although I don't really know what the Record type is capable of.

Comment: @Wingnod you are correct. Record is similarly restricted, so my example could have been `Record<string | number, any>`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [`object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object) is meant to abstract away any keys of an object, whereas [`Record<K, T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/af8e44ac85a46ead640b3204a6e4c333641cf945/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1379-L1384) exists to specifically define the keys of a type. This means there is a **difference when trying to access object properties**.

TypeScript will allow to access any property of an object of type `Record<any, any>` even though the specific keys are not known, since the first generic parameter is `any`.

```
let a: Record<any, any>;
a.foo; // works
```

On an object of type `object` however, the keys are *not* assumed to be `any`. As with `Record<any, ...>`, TypeScript does not know which keys actually exist, but it will not allow to access any keys:

```
let b: object;
a.foo; // error: Property "foo" does not exist on type "object"
```

Try it in the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20a%3A%20Record%3Cany%2C%20any%3E%3B%0D%0Aa.foo%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20b%3A%20object%3B%0D%0Ab.foo%3B%0D%0A).

Comment: So why would I ever want to use `object`, if that effectively precludes me from accessing any of the properties?

Comment: @BehindTheMath One use-case can be if you're writing a polyfill for your native js object. You still would want the method names, their return types etc. to be respected right?

Comment: Does this two approaches `Record<any, any>` and `{ [key: any}: any }` give the same result?

Comment: `Record` is declared as `type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T; }`, so `Record<A, B>` is equivalent to `{ [key: A]: B; }`

Comment: The other reason `Record<K, V>` exists in TS is because we can't use `Object<K, V>`. `Object` isn't what it seems to be so TS added Record.