# interface is not assignable to type Record<string, unknown>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have create a generic react component as following:

```
export interface GenericTableProps<T extends Record<string, unknown>> {
  columns: Column<T>[];
  data: T[];
}

const GenericTable = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>({
  columns,
  data,
}: GenericTableProps<T>): ReactElement => {
  ...
}
```

This is how I use this component:

```
const data: StudentsDto[] = useMemo(() => tableData ?? [], [tableData]);
const columns: Column<StudentsDto>[] = useMemo(() => tableColumns, []);
<GenericTable columns={columns} data={data} />
```

This gives me a typescript error:

```
Type 'StudentsDto[]' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>[]'.
  Type 'StudentsDto' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'.
    Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'StudentsDto'
```

`StudentsDto` looks as following:

```
export interface StudentsDto {
  index?: number;
  name?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  dob?: string;
  ...
}
```

I should mention that I can't update `StudentsDto` interface, since it's generated using openApi.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: What about `Column`  -> `columns: Column<T>[];`. It´s some interface that you created or some 3rd library ? Can you add it and also `tableData` and `tableColumns` structure? Without that its difficult to produce your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is due to typescript's type inference ([here's the official doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html), and a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37006179/1974681) that can help to understand it)

As @subrato-pattanaik well spotted, `unknown` should be used when you will narrow types afterwards. And you can use `any` to accept any type.

For your particular case, if you need to make the interface `GenericTableProps` to accept different types...

- and some of them you do not know at the moment: I'd use an `object` type, since it is more readable than `Record<string, any>` (differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52246786/1974681))

  ```js
  export interface GenericTableProps<T extends object> {
  //...
  ```
- and you know all of them: I'd create a new interface extending all the types that `GenericTableProps` can accept, and use that particular type. This approach is the preferred one because you will have narrower types, and that can help you avoid type errors.

  ```js
  interface GenericTableDataType extends StudentsDto, ProfessorsDto {}

  export interface GenericTableProps<T extends GenericTableDataType> {
  //...
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The most direct answer is to use `Record<string, any>` instead of `Record<string, unknown>`. The general use case of `unknown` type is when we have to narrow down the types. For example,

```
function fn(g: unknown) {
  if(typeof g === 'string'){
   g; //here g would be string
   console.log(g.toLowerCase()); // typescript will not yell us about wrong types
  }
 
  if(typeof g === 'function'){
   g; // function type
   console.log(g.name); // can access name property of function
  }
}
```

With `Record<string, any>` type means that we are assured that it will match with `any object` and `not any type` whether they have inferred index signature or not.

The obvious reason why it works with `Record<string, any>` and not `Record<string, unknow>` is given here in this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42825#issuecomment-789242594).

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove `extends Record<string, unknown>` or add an index signature to your type `const data: StudentsDto & {[key: string]: unknown}[] = ...`