# Equating Record<string, unknown> with a generic object while defining function parameters

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to remove empty values from a general object using the code below.

```
const cleanObject = (object: Record<string, unknown>) => {
  Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
      cleanObject(value); // --> warning seen here
    }
    if (
      (value && typeof value === 'object' && !Object.keys(value).length) ||
      value === null ||
      value === undefined ||
      value === ''
    ) {
      if (Array.isArray(object)) {
        object.splice(Number(key), 1);
      } else {
        delete object[key];
      }
    }
  });
  return object;
};
```

While passing `value` to `cleanObject`, I see the following warning.

> Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, unknown>'.
> Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '{}'.

Is there a way to avoid this, without explicitly annotating `value as Record<string, unknown`?

Comment: Are you guarenteed that the general object will only ever have keys of string and not number and Symbol. (This is what typescript is warning you about)

Comment: @zecuria In the context that this function is being used, the keys will only be of type string or number (as the value can be an array). It does not make a difference though, if I change the param type to `Record<string | number, unknown>)`

Comment: Yep my bad, the reason is that you are using `unknown` instead of `any`. Reasons and relevant links are provided: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72583534/2967697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by creating general types to represent the object data I was expecting.

```
type ObjectValue = number | string | boolean | GeneralArray | GeneralObject;
type GeneralObject = { [key: string]: ObjectValue };
type GeneralArray = Array<ObjectValue>;

/**
 * Removes all the null,  empty objects, "" (empty string values), undefined values from the object
 */
const cleanObject = (object: GeneralObject | GeneralArray) => {
  Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
      cleanObject(value);
    }
    if (
      (value && typeof value === 'object' && !Object.keys(value).length) ||
      value === null ||
      value === undefined ||
      value === ''
    ) {
      if (Array.isArray(object)) {
        object.splice(Number(key), 1);
      } else {
        delete object[key];
      }
    }
  });
  return object;
};
```