# Apply same function to different objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Let's say I have a couple of functions (they're GraphQL resolvers but I don't think it's that relevant):

```
function doSomething: (args: doSomethingInput) => {
  const { id, accessToken, type } = args.input
  // more code here that uses those variables...
}

function doSomethingElse: (args: doSomethingElseInput) => {
  const { id, accessToken, points } = args.input
  // more code here that uses those variables...
}

type doSomethingInput = {
  input: { id: string, accessToken: string, type: string }
}

type doSomethingElseInput = {
  input: { id: string, accessToken: string, points: string }
}
```

I would like to sanitize the input that's passed to those function, so my idea is to do something like this using the [validator library](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js):

```
import validator from 'validator'

function doSomething: (args: doSomethingInput) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(args.input)) {
    const keyTyped = key as keyof typeof args.input
    args.input[keyTyped] = validator.escape(value)
  }

  const { id, accessToken, type } = args.input
  // more code here that uses those variables...
}
```

This would allow, for example, that an `accessToken` that was passed as such `28502307<script>alert('HELLO')</script>` to my function will then look like this `28502307&lt;script&gt;alert(&#x27;HELLO&#x27;)&lt;&#x2F;script&gt;` which I prefer.

However, I would like to apply this to the input of *all* my resolvers.
That's why I would like to write a function to externalize that behavior:

```
import validator from 'validator'

function sanitize(inputParameters: object): object {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(inputParameters)) {
    inputParameters[key] = validator.escape(value as string)
  }

  return inputParameters
}
```

However it gives me this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.
```

And this doesn't work either:

```
import validator from 'validator'

function sanitize(inputParameters: object): object {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(inputParameters)) {
    const keyTyped = key as keyof typeof inputParameters
    inputParameters[keyTyped] = validator.escape(value as string)
  }

  return inputParameters
}
```

this time with this error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

(I found that typecast line somewhere else in here in stackoverflow)

So, how can apply a generic function to objects with different types?

Comment: "So, how can apply a generic function to objects with different types" you were soooo close, the feature you want is literally called "generics": https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to get started. Right now you're using private or pseudocode types and values like `doSomethingInput`, and the question appears to depend on the validatorjs library and therefore requires that people hunt down those typings. If you can make it self contained so that anyone can easily reproduce your issue by pasting into their own IDEs, you'll have a better chance of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your `inputParameters` will contain, but you cannot access arbitrary keys of `object` type (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52246786/15076557)). So instead I recommend you use the `Record` type with `any` as key (allowing any string or number key) and `unknown` value type (allows for any value, but continues to check the type).

If you don't know `inputParameters` value types ahead of time, you might want to check them first, since using `as` assertion (`value as string`) just disabled most of typescript checks and can lead to undesired consequences. Instead you can check if `value` is a `string` with `typeof value === 'string'` and if it's not, ignore the value (or go deeper if the value itself is a `Record`).

---

Here's the `sanitize` function with `Record` type:

```
function sanitize(inputParameters: Record<any, unknown>): Record<any, unknown> {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(inputParameters)) {
    inputParameters[key] = validator.escape(value as string)
  }

  return inputParameters
}
```

More on `Record` in the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type),